# loop code 1,000,000 times and find probability C coding

Tags: c

Task of the project given is to make the game craps. I have the game completed, however now I must have the game play 1,000,000 times and note; [games won by player][games won by house] and [percent probability of player wins][percent probability of house wins]. I am new to coding, {How do I loop 1,000,000 times?}

My code is as follows;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void play_craps();

int main(void)


{
int rand_int(int a, int b);
srand(time(NULL));

int die_1,die_2,die_3,die_4,roll,roll_2;

die_1=rand_int(1,6);
die_2=rand_int(1,6);
roll=die_1 + die_2;
printf("You rolled a %i\n",roll);

if(roll==7 || roll==11)
    {
        printf("You Win!\n");
        return;
    }
else if(roll==2 || roll==3 || roll==12)
    {
        printf("You Lose\n");
        return;
    }
else
    {
        do
        {

            die_3=rand_int(1,6);
            die_4=rand_int(1,6);
            roll_2=die_3 + die_4;
            printf("You rolled a %i\n",roll_2);
            if(roll_2==roll)
             {
                 printf("You Win");
                 return;
             }
        }while(roll_2 != 7);

    printf("You Lose");
    }

}
int rand_int(int a, int b)
{

return rand()%(b-a+1)+a;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Move your repeated code to a function, which will return a value corresponding to win/draw/loss and run it in a loop counting the outcomes.

Comment: If you're going to simulate 1,000,000 games, I strongly suggest you reduce the verbosity.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

I have commented the unnecessary `printf()` statements otherwise the code takes 10-20s to run.

The function named `this_function_will_loop()` is the one that loops for `1,000,000` times and it returns `1` if a player wins and `0` if the house wins. Then the number of wins by the player is simply counted in the `main()` function and percent probability is calculated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//void play_craps();
int rand_int(int a, int b);

int this_function_will_loop(){
int die_1,die_2,die_3,die_4,roll,roll_2;

    die_1=rand_int(1,6);
    die_2=rand_int(1,6);
    roll=die_1 + die_2;
    //printf("You rolled a %i\n",roll);

    if(roll==7 || roll==11)
    {
        //printf("You Win!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(roll==2 || roll==3 || roll==12)
    {
        //printf("You Lose\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            die_3=rand_int(1,6);
            die_4=rand_int(1,6);
            roll_2=die_3 + die_4;
            //printf("You rolled a %i\n",roll_2);
            if(roll_2==roll)
            {
                //printf("You Win");
                return 1;
            }
        }while(roll_2 != 7);
        //printf("You Lose");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int ans = 0;
    int loop_times = 1'000'000;
    for(int i = 1; i<=loop_times;i++){
        ans+=this_function_will_loop();
    }
    printf("Total games played = %d\n", loop_times);
    printf("Games won by player = %d\n", ans);
    printf("Games won by house = %d\n", loop_times - ans);
    printf("Percent probability of player wins  = %f\n", 100.0*(ans*1.0/loop_times));
    printf("Percent probability of house wins  = %f\n", 100.0*((loop_times - ans)*1.0/loop_times));
    return 0;
}

int rand_int(int a, int b)
{
return rand()%(b-a+1)+a;
}
```

Currently it takes 5-6s to run

```
Here's the output I got:
Total games played = 1000000
Games won by player = 492773
Games won by house = 507227
Percent probability of player wins  = 49.277300
Percent probability of house wins  = 50.722700
```

Comment: this is understandable, thankyou and line 49 "int loop_times = 1'000'000;" the (') instead of (,) is something I have not seen before

Comment: @zone Yeah. I also saw it a couple of weeks back. Its just a way to represent big numbers in a readable format.

Comment: @zone If the answer helped you and meets your needs, you can consider accepting it :)